# Infinispan cache does not throw exception in pessimistic mode

Tags: java, unit-testing, infinispan, pessimistic-locking

I am running simple test case based on one of the **Infinispan** unit tests. In my test I expect to receive `CacheException` when replication timeouts in my cluster.

I use pessimistic transaction locking and exception is not thrown in this case for some reason. If I comment pessimistic locking I get exception as expected.

```
@Test(groups = "functional", testName = "replication.ReplicationExceptionTest")
public class ReplicationExceptionTest extends MultipleCacheManagersTest {

    protected void createCacheManagers() {
        ConfigurationBuilder configuration = getDefaultClusteredCacheConfig(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC, true);
        configuration.locking()
                .lockAcquisitionTimeout(60000l)
                .transaction().transactionManagerLookup(new DummyTransactionManagerLookup());
                // uncomment this line and exception is not thrown for some reason
                //.lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC);
        createClusteredCaches(2, configuration);
        waitForClusterToForm();
    }

    @Test(groups = "functional", expectedExceptions = { CacheException.class })
    public void testSyncReplTimeout() {
        AdvancedCache cache1 = cache(0).getAdvancedCache();
        AdvancedCache cache2 = cache(1).getAdvancedCache();
        cache2.addInterceptor(new CommandInterceptor() {
            @Override
            protected Object handleDefault(InvocationContext ctx, VisitableCommand cmd)
                    throws Throwable {
                // Add a delay
                Thread.sleep(100);
                return super.handleDefault(ctx, cmd);
            }
        }, 0);

        cache1.getCacheConfiguration().clustering().sync().replTimeout(10);
        cache2.getCacheConfiguration().clustering().sync().replTimeout(10);
        TestingUtil.blockUntilViewsReceived(10000, cache1, cache2);

        cache1.put("k", "v");
    }

}
```

Can someone help me understand why it is hiding exception with pessimistic locking enabled and how to fix that?

Update: I am using Infinispan 5.3.0.Final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Infinispan registers itself with the transaction manager by default as a "synchronization" instead of a full XA resource. Synchronizations are not allowed to throw XAExceptions in their `afterCompletion()` methods, and the transaction managers (including `DummyTransactionManagerLookup`) swallow any runtime exceptions.

In optimistic mode, the keys and values are replicated during  `beforeCompletion()`, which is allowed to throw an exception in order to cancel the transaction.

In pessimistic mode, you should configure Infinispan to register as an XA resource instead:

```
   configuration.transaction().useSynchronization(false);
```

Edit: By default, `DummyTransactionManager` doesn't support XA transactions, so you also need to configure it for XA (or even better, use Narayana):

```
    DummyTransactionManager.getInstance().setUseXaXid(true);
```

Comment: This is really helpful, I would never figure out this combination. Thanks a lot